# Excluir caractere em uma determinada posição?

Tags: linux, shell, bash, delete, unix

Como faço para excluir um determinado caractere em uma determinada posição em shell?

Já tentei com `sed`, mas não consigo colocar a posição também, apenas o padrão.

```
",45123","B23142DHAS675"
```

O que queria era apagar a `,` que está na segunda posição da string, porém caso não haja `,` nada deve fazer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
~$ echo ",45123","B23142DHAS675" | sed 's/.//7'
,45123B23142DHAS675
```

Onde `7` é a posição do caractere a ser removido. Uma outra alternativa:

```
~$ echo ",45123","B23142DHAS675" | sed 's/\,//2'
,45123B23142DHAS675
```

O comando acima remove a segunda ocorrência de `,`.

Comment: Na verdade eu gostaria que o resultado fosse:
"45123","B23142DHAS675"  - que somente apagasse a "," que está na segunda posição.

Comment: Perfeito, @DBX8! Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Use uma expressão regular que guarde os primeiros `n - 1` caracteres, verifique se o caracter `n` é o que você quer, e guarde os caracteres restantes.

```
 echo "abcdef nao sera removido
a,cdef será removido
A,BCD será removido" | sed -r 's/^(.),(.*)$/\1\2/'
```

Resultado:

```
abcdef nao sera removido
acdef será removido
ABCD será removido
```

Comment: Gostaria que somente apagasse a "," da segunda posição, e não o conteúdo inteiro. Que o resultado ficasse assim: 
Na verdade eu gostaria que o resultado fosse: "45123","B23142DHAS675"